# Angular ng-repeat ng-click parameter not passed to function call, why?

Tags: angularjs

I have a short plunker with the details.
Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a list of buttons with a click function and the function doesn't get the item - it returns the literal name of the variable. Very strange.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hFt91zkF8lZiPVvfvS4R?p=preview

```
<li ng-repeat="comp in listOfItems"><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click='onSearchBtnClick("{{ comp }}")' >{{ comp }}</button></li>
```

the list of buttons is shown correctly and in the chrome dev tools it shows the correct function call as:

```
ng-click="onSearchBtnClick("when")"
```

The manually added `<li>` works as expected. the others get `{{ comp }}` as the string instead of the value of it.

Comment: Try removing the `{{ }}` from `{{comp}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like below you don't need the `{{ }}` inside `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat="comp in listOfItems"><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click='onSearchBtnClick(comp)' >
```

> `ng-click` evaluate a expression here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), so you dont need to put `{{  }}`

[updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zuC4nJ1VOEGAHUMeDK9c?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `onSearchBtnClick(comp)`.  The property exists on scope and does not need to be interpolated.  By  using `""` you are actually using a string literal as an argument and thus passing in `"{{ comp }}"`, literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following expression.

```
<li ng-repeat="comp in listOfItems"><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="onSearchBtnClick('{{comp}}')" ></li>
```